# Swift application is not updated when using IBM microclimate

Tags: ibm-cloud-functions, microclimate

I created a default swift application using IBM microclimate which I installed locally and the default application works fine. However when I update the home page of the application I cannot get the home page displayed to reflect the changes I made.

Answer (score 0):

There is a issue with IBM Microclimate where it does not automatically detect changes in a Swift application and make them available. In order to work around this issue you must stop Microclimate using the "mcdev stop" command and then re-start it using the "mcdev start" command. This will result in the application being re-built and deployed based on the changes made.